# Summoning Structure Blocks With Instructions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering. I know you can summon command blocks with instructions in them, but can you do wit with structure blocks? I would love it if there was a command that summoned a load structure block with "Spaceship", "~ ~+1 ~" and "include entities" on it. Thanks! I hope I provided enough information!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not think that there is a command that allows you to do this, but you can put the structure block in a location with the information inside of it and then clone the structure block to a different location with a command block.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could, either by using /setblock with a data tag to place one, or by making it on the ground and using ctrl + pickblock (defaults to mouse3) to get a copy with NBT data in your inventory (this could also be done with command if you really wanted to.